# Problem with adding products to WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to add some products to WooCommerce and I have a class for this. This is my public insert function:

```js
public function insert()
{
    $this->_insert_product();
    $this->_update_variations();
    $this->_update_featured_image();
    $this->_update_attributes();
    $this->_update_categories();
    $this->_update_tags();
    $this->_update_custom_fields();
    $this->_update_product_price();
    $this->_update_sku();
    $this->_update_stock();
    return true;
}
```

This will insert product, insert variations and some other stuff going on. The problem is with stock! When I add my product everything is fine and correct but for variable products, when I save product using admin panel or purchase one item from that product, the product will goes outofstock and I do not want that for sure. Variations are still instock and user can buy the product without a problem but product out of stock badge shows on the product and status is out of stock in admin panel. Can I use some help?

```js
private function _update_stock()
{
    // $this->id is product id
    // This will generate $this->stock variable (0 or 1 or 2 and etc)
    $this->_generate_stock();
    // If product type is simple just update product stock and stock status
    // This is working just fine
    if ($this->type == 'simple') {
        update_post_meta($this->id, '_manage_stock', 'yes');
        update_post_meta($this->id, '_stock', $this->stock);
        if ($this->stock > 0) update_post_meta($this->id, '_stock_status', 'instock');
        else update_post_meta($this->id, '_stock_status', 'outofstock');
        update_post_meta($this->id, '_backorders', 'no');
    }
    // Else if product type is variable (PROBLEM IS HERE)
    else {
        // Variable to store if any of variations has stock
        $has_stock = false;
        // $this->variations is an array of variations ids
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($this->variations); $i++) {
            // Enable stock management for variation
            update_post_meta($this->variations[$i], '_manage_stock', 'yes');
            // Update stock ($this->stock is an array of stocks for each variation)
            update_post_meta($this->variations[$i], '_stock', $this->stock[$i]);
            // Disable backorders
            update_post_meta($this->variations[$i], '_backorders', 'no');
            // If variation has stock update stock status to in stock
            if ($this->stock[$i] > 0) {
                update_post_meta($this->variations[$i], '_stock_status', 'instock');
                $has_stock = true;
            }
            // Else update stock status to out of stock
            else update_post_meta($this->variations[$i], '_stock_status', 'outofstock');
        }
        // Sync variation
        WC_Product_Variable::sync($this->id);
        // Update stock status of main product
        if ($has_stock) update_post_meta($this->id, '_stock_status', 'instock');
        else update_post_meta($this->id, '_stock_status', 'outofstock');
    }
}
```

```js
private function _insert_product()
{
    $this->_generate_title();
    $this->_generate_permalink();
    $this->_generate_content();
    $this->_generate_excerpt();
    $this->_generate_post_status();
    $post = array(
        'post_title' => $this->title,
        'post_name' => sanitize_title($this->permalink),
        'post_content' => $this->content,
        'post_status' => $this->post_status,
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'post_excerpt' => $this->excerpt,
        'tax_input' => array('product_type' => $this->type),
    );
    $this->id = wp_insert_post($post);
}
```

```js
private function _update_variations()
{
    if ($this->type == 'variable') {
        $attribute_id = $this->options['import_attribute_for_variations'];
        $attribute = wc_get_attribute($attribute_id);
        $attributes = [];
        $attributes[$attribute->slug] = array(
            'name' => $attribute->slug,
            'value' => '',
            'position' => '0',
            'is_visible' => '0',
            'is_variation' => '1',
            'is_taxonomy' => '1'
        );
        update_post_meta($this->id, '_product_attributes', $attributes);
        $variation_name_index = $this->options['import_variation_name'];
        $variations = [];
        foreach ($this->product as $variation) {
            $variation_name = $variation[$variation_name_index];
            array_push($variations, $variation_name);
        }
        wp_set_object_terms($this->id, $variations, $attribute->slug);
        foreach ($this->product as $variation) {
            $variation_name = $variation[$variation_name_index];
            $variation = array(
                'post_title'   => $this->title . ' - ' . $variation_name,
                'post_content' => '',
                'post_status'  => 'publish',
                'post_parent'  => $this->id,
                'post_type'    => 'product_variation',
            );
            $variation_id = wp_insert_post($variation);
            update_post_meta($variation_id, 'attribute_' . $attribute->slug, sanitize_title($variation_name));
            $this->variations[] = $variation_id;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should call WC_Product_Variable::sync($this->id); after you've updated all variations, not within the loop. This method synchronizes the variable product with its variations and should be called once all variations have been updated.

Comment: @user580950 yes I tried that, but still the problem is here.

Comment: update the question with what you did so I can check

Comment: @user580950 I moved it after my loop

Comment: After updating all variations, you're calling WC_Product_Variable::sync($this->id);. Make sure this function call is after the loop that updates all variations. Instead of manually setting the stock status of the variable product, let WooCommerce handle it based on its variations. Remove the manual update of the variable product's stock status and rely on the synchronization process to set it correctly.

Comment: @user580950 I removed `Update stock status of main product` section and now when products are outofstock from the beginning but variations are fine and purchasable.

Comment: Check the  answer I posted

Comment: Since WooCommerce 3, you should use available CRUD methods instead of WordPress functions, as WooCommerce is progressively migrating to custom database tables. The provided code is not testable, so nobody can really guess and find out what the problem is, giving a useful working answer… see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in the comment I removed the manual update of the variable product stock status and allowed WooCommerce to automatically sync the variable products status based on its variations stock status. I hope that help in fixing the issue

```
private function _update_stock()
{
    $this->_generate_stock();
    if ($this->type == 'simple') {
        update_post_meta($this->id, '_manage_stock', 'yes');
        update_post_meta($this->id, '_stock', $this->stock);
        update_post_meta($this->id, '_stock_status', $this->stock > 0 ? 'instock' : 'outofstock');
        update_post_meta($this->id, '_backorders', 'no');
    } else {
        foreach ($this->variations as $i => $variation_id) {
            update_post_meta($variation_id, '_manage_stock', 'yes');
            update_post_meta($variation_id, '_stock', $this->stock[$i]);
            update_post_meta($variation_id, '_backorders', 'no');
            update_post_meta($variation_id, '_stock_status', $this->stock[$i] > 0 ? 'instock' : 'outofstock');
        }
        WC_Product_Variable::sync($this->id);
        WC_Product_Variable::sync_stock_status($this->id);

    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but as I said, products now are outofstock from the beginning but variations are fine and purchasable.

Comment: Answer updated to sync the parent product's stock status after updating all variations:

Comment: Still the same problem, I added other functions that may be the problem